# Current value of EditText not being passed to a function from onCreate()

Tags: android, json, api, android-layout, android-volley

I am building an android app that displays the COVID19 statistics for India, I am getting the stats in JSON format from https://api.covid19india.org/data.json , this API contains data of individual states too,

Below is the snip of Json array(contains json objects representing each state) that i am requesting

[image]

as of Now i am displaying the entire data ( all states ) at a time on my screen, However i want to give the state name as the input and display the stats of only that state For eg. in the below image in place of sample i want to write a state name and the stats of that state must be displayed on click of the button.

[image]

Here is the code of mainActivity.java, I am using Volley Library for fetching data from API

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView result;
    private RequestQueue mq;
    public String value;
    int flag = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Button parse = findViewById(R.id.button);

        mq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.state_ip);
        value = text.getText().toString();

        parse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                jsonParse(value); 
                **//How do i pass 'value' i.e the state name entered by user to jsonParse**
            }
        });
    }

    private void jsonParse(final String value) {

        Log.d("val_state",value);
        String url = "https://api.covid19india.org/data.json";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("statewise");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject st = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String statename = st.getString("state");
                                String active = st.getString("active");
                                String confirmed = st.getString("confirmed");
                                String deaths = st.getString("deaths");
                                String recovered = st.getString("recovered");
                                if(statename.equals(value))
                                {
                                    flag= 1;
                                }

                                statename = "State : " + statename;
                                active = "Active Cases : " + active;
                                confirmed = "Confirmed Cases : " + confirmed;
                                deaths = "Total Deaths : " + deaths;
                                recovered = "Total Recovered : " + recovered;
                                if(flag==1)
                                {
                                    flag=0;
                                     result.append(statename + "\n" + String.valueOf(active) + "\n" + String.valueOf(confirmed) + "\n" + String.valueOf(deaths) + "\n" + String.valueOf(recovered) + "\n\n\n");
            } 
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mq.add(request);
    }
}
```

Here , i want to pass the value of state entered by the user to the method jsonParse() so that i check the state name with the received JSON data and append it to the TextView, but when i do this , and try to log the value inside the jsonParse() method i get nothing, why is this happening , How do i implement the above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EditText value is update and has to be captured after the button is clicked.

```
parse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            value = text.getText().toString();
            jsonParse(value);
        }
    });
```